# codeigniter 2 and smarty 3 : multi array of stdClass results returned - how do i display these in smarty

Tags: arrays, codeigniter-2, stdclass, smarty3

My Sql function getLive_projects has this query -
    $query = "SELECT p.* FROM projects p WHERE p.live = 1 ORDER BY client_name ASC";
    $response = $this->db->query($query)->result();

My Controller :
    // get live projects
    $data['live_projects'] = $this->projects->get_live_projects();
    // load the projects with the data
    $this->parser->parse("projects.tpl", $data);

The data in my template looks like this when I use {$live_projects|print_r}

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [client_name] => client one
        [dev_url] => clientone.com
        [live_url] => clientone.com
        [version] => 1.0
        [live] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [client_name] => client two
        [dev_url] => clienttwo.com
        [live_url] => clienttwo.com
        [version] => 3.1
        [live] => 1
    )
```

)

How can I output this in my template? I tried {foreach from=$live_projects item=$project} and then tried to use {$project->client_name} but that didn't work. Should the object not be available to me when I loop over the array? Have I missed something obvious? Am I going about this in the right way? I just want to loop over the returned results and display each one as a row in my template.

I have searched the forums but was unable to find an answer that solved my issue - any help would be much appreciated. There are some example out there about using $live_projects[0]->id but how can this be incorporated into output from smarty where many items are returned in the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there! When defining the name of your item variable, you don't have to include the '$' sign. Change your code to:

```
{foreach from=$live_projects item=project}
    {$project->client_name}
{/foreach}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: ahh man that is such a schoolboy error, tired late night coding - lesson learned. cheers for the reply dude.